# How to connect a local database in a sandbox environment?

Tags: 2010, sql-server, virtual-machine

I have the following scenario:

I am very new to Sharepoint 2010 development. In order to practice I had to create a sandbox. Therefore I was instructed to do the following steps:

1. Get **Windows 8**
2. Create a Virtual machine using **Hyper-V**, which apparently comes with Windows 8, oob.
3. Install **Windows Server 2008 R2** on my VM.
4. Install **Sharepoint Server 2010** on the VM.
5. Install **Visual Studio 2012**.
6. Try to develop custom Webparts etc.

Further there is a **SQL-Server database** in the local network. I am also supposed to connect to this database. This is where my problems begin. I still did not manage to get Windows 8 and have to use Windows 7, so no Hyper-V. That is why I decided to choose another approach.

On my Windows 7 machine I installed VirtualBox and did all the stuff from the list above in it. But here is the problem. I am able to connect to the database from my Client machine, but the VM is not registered in the domain so I am not able to connect it in my developement environment. So finally my question.

Is it possible to somehow create a *local* sql server database in my VM an connect it as I would normally do?

Note: Normally I would simply try to connect a Shrepoint list to this database using **Sharepoint Designer** as described [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=794).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I solved this problem.

I simply installed SQL Server 2008 on my VM so I was able to create a database which I then could connect to on the very same VM.